# Не могу отдать значения из бд пользователю node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Я делаю:

```
let con = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : conf.get('db').connection,
        user     : conf.get('db').user,
        password : conf.get('db').pass, 
        database : conf.get('db').database
    });
    con.query('SELECT * FROM `clothing`', function(error, result, fields){
        if(error == null){
            var presets = [];
            result.forEach(function(v, i){
                presets.push({
                    'name': v.name,
                    'torso': [v.torso_draw, v.torso_tex],
                    'legs': [v.legs_draw, v.legs_tex],
                    'foot': [v.foot_draw, v.foot_tex],
                    'torso_acc': [v.torso_acc_draw, v.torso_acc_tex],
                    'hands': [v.hands_draw, v.hands_tex],
                    'helmet': [v.helmet_draw, v.helmet_tex],
                    'mask': [v.mask_draw, v.mask_tex]
                });
            });
            response.json(presets);
        } else{
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

И мне дает ошибку что headers уже отправлены, хотя если после con.query() отправить response.json() то такой ошибки не будет. Пробовал return presets, но он тогда пишет undefined, просто не возвращаются. Если сделал console.log() то значения есть в presets, но как их юзеру отправить??

Comment: С`Express'ом`  не дружу, в нативной Node, запрос в БД я оборачивал в отдельную функцию с коллбэком, и в коллбэке уже отправлял ответ

Comment: сколько раз у вас отрабатывает ваш участок кода? грубо говоря когда вы делаете  console.log() то значения есть в presets сколько раз вы видите это значение? где то еще в коде у вас задействован обьект response? ошибка с headers возникает когда ответ отправляется несколько раз и заголовки перезаписываются

Comment: @torokhkun 1 раз запускаю query, а до этого есть response.header('Content-Type', 'application/json'); 
response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); чтобы запрос ajax дошел без ошибки.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вынес работу с базой данных в отдельную функцию (а в идеале в отдельный модуль).

Как то так

```
const doQuery = callback => {
  const connection = require('mysql').createConnection({
    host: conf.get('db').connection,
    user: conf.get('db').user,
    password: conf.get('db').pass,
    database: conf.get('db').database
  });
  const presets = [];

  connection.connect();
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM `clothing`', (err, results, fields) => {
    if (err) return callback(err, null);

    results.forEach((v, i) => {
      presets.push({
        'name': v.name,
        'torso': [v.torso_draw, v.torso_tex],
        'legs': [v.legs_draw, v.legs_tex],
        'foot': [v.foot_draw, v.foot_tex],
        'torso_acc': [v.torso_acc_draw, v.torso_acc_tex],
        'hands': [v.hands_draw, v.hands_tex],
        'helmet': [v.helmet_draw, v.helmet_tex],
        'mask': [v.mask_draw, v.mask_tex]
      });
    });

    connection.end();
    callback(null, presets);
  });
};

// вызов в app (в промышленном использовании следует добавить обработку ошибок)
doQuery((err, result) => response.json(presets));
```

Comment: presets is not defined на строчке callback(null, presets); пробовал создавать presets внутри query, та же ошибка, при этом console.log(presets) в query выдает [], а не undefined.

Comment: может какие то непечатные символи при копировании из редактора... у вас проект учебный или промышленная разработка? есть возможность выложить на гитхаб и дать ссылку?

Comment: Промышленная разработка, сервер гта 5. Могу дать эту часть кода, и скажу что есть клиент гта 5, в котором html страница отображается, где есть выбор пресетов, и вот через json идет отправка на этот api для получения списка пресетов. Поэтому я добавил в начале headers.

Comment: response.header('Content-Type', 'application/json'); вот это уберите. response json его добавит. это дублирование
а в паре с response.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
лучше добавить res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, MOVE, OPTIONS');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');

Comment: Сделал все это, но он все еще не видит presets, хотя console.log его видит.. console.log(presets); callback(null, presets); вроде рядом выполняю, а результат абсолютно разный